# show part of wraped lines in vim instead of hiding it with the @ character

Tags: vim

I use `vim` not only for coding but also for text writing. In this context I use the wrap and linebreak options to wrap my text. Since lines - forming paragraphs in text writing - can be very long a wraped line easily does not fit in the lower part of the screen so `vim` hides all the wrapped line replacing the visible part of it with the @ symbol.

Is there any chance to avoid this so that `vim` just shows the part of the wraped line that still fits at the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're looking for

```
set display=lastline    " Show as much as possible of a wrapped last line, not just "@".
```

Put this into your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: thx. that's it. Unfortunately my google search did not lead me into this direction.